# Discretize a xarray.DataArray

Tags: python, python-xarray, binning

Let's say that I have an array made of floats, and for each point I would like to convert its float value to a certain integer, depending on the bin/range where this float value falls:

The best I could came up with is this. Surely there must a shorter way?

EDIT: Ideally it would be nice to control also the mapped values, e.g `[np.inf, 6.6, 3.3, -np.inf]` --> `[10,5,-3]`.

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

da = xr.DataArray(np.random.uniform(0,10,[10,10]), 
             dims=['x','y'], coords=[range(10), range(10)])

labels = {'high':1, 'medium':0, 'low':-1}

binned = da.groupby_bins(da, [-np.inf, 3.3, 6.6, np.inf], labels=labels.keys())

def fix_up_binned(label):
    # make sure binned dataarray match the initial one
    # for dimensions and coordinates
    da_cat = dict(binned)[label].unstack()
    da_cat = da_cat.sortby(['x', 'y'])
    da_cat = da_cat.reindex({'x': da.x.values,'y': da.y.values,})
    return da_cat

das_fixed = []
for label, value in labels.items():
    da_fixed = fix_up_binned(label)
    das_fixed.append(da_fixed.where(~da_fixed.notnull(), value))

discrete = xr.concat(das_fixed, list(labels.keys())).sum('concat_dim')
discrete = xr.where(da.notnull(), discrete, np.nan) # needed in case the initial array contains nans
```

A visual demonstration that this works:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,5))
da.plot(ax=ax[0], vmin=-0.001, vmax=10.001, levels=4)
discrete.plot(col_wrap=4, vmin=-1.001, vmax=1.001, cmap='RdYlGn',levels=4, ax=ax[1])
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
discrete = da.copy()

discrete_values = np.array([-5,0,5])
bins = [-np.inf, 3.3, 6.6, np.inf]

discrete.values = np.take(discrete_values, np.digitize(discrete.values, bins) - 1, axis=0)
```

If you don't need da anymore you can save yourself the memory and time of making a copy and just update `da` inplace.

Comment: great! looks like the bins argument should be inverted, i.e. `[np.inf, 6.6, 3.3, -np.inf]` though. ideally it would be nice to have more control on the mapped values, e.g `[np.inf, 6.6, 3.3, -np.inf]` --> `[10,5,-3]` (I'll edit my question)

Comment: If you want to control that you'll need to do an extra step at the end. You can just write a function, let's say values_map(x) that maps integer to your desired label. Then you can do `discrete.values = np.vectorize(values_map)(discrete.values)`.

Comment: I see you have added `np.take`. What's this doing? It would be very useful also for future readers to have some explanations in your code.

Comment: It's mapping to values. Would recommend reading the numpy documentation for the inbuilt functions.